# Online Chess Communities

Tags: websites

What are some of the thriving chess community websites online. Let me start with a few examples:

[Chess community on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/)

[Chess.com has a huge community](https://www.chess.com/forum/)

[Chess India Community](http://chessindia.net)

What are the other chess related forums and community websites on the internet where Chess related discussions happen everyday?

Comment: I didn't include this stack exchange community in this early list, because I thought that it was a Q/A site, with less possibility for social interaction. Correct me if I am wrong. ;)

Comment: Even Quora in not included in this list since it falls into the Q/A types in my line of thinking.

Comment: talkchess.com is definitely the most technical chess community.

Comment: I would mention chessgames.com. They have the most creative trolls.

Answer (score 1):

- [Chess community on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/)
- [Chess.com has a huge community](https://www.chess.com/forum/)
- [Chess India Community](http://chessindia.net)
- [TalkChess community](http://talkchess.com/)  Thanks @StudentT
- [Chessgames.com](http://chessgames.com) Thanks @BlindKungFuMaster

Updating this list with all the suggestions, and my own findings.